# docker-compose how to link an exist mariadb rather than create a new one

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

The application compose file is:

```
version: '2'

    services:
      db:
        image: mariadb:10.1
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: filerun
          MYSQL_USER: filerun
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: filerun
          MYSQL_DATABASE: filerun
        volumes:
          - /filerun/db:/var/lib/mysql

      web:
        depends_on:
          - db
        links:
          - db
        image: afian/filerun
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        volumes:
          - /filerun/html:/var/www/html
          - /filerun/user-files:/user-files
```

it seems like a new mariadb(web_db_1) will be created, but How to use an already exists mariadb run with `docker run --name mariadb -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passwordhere -d mariadb:latest`

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to a container created outside docker-compose with the statement [external_links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links):

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    external_links:
      - mariadb
    image: afian/filerun
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /filerun/html:/var/www/html
      - /filerun/user-files:/user-files
```